# How to name a html element on a page based on its OuterHtml?

Tags: html, xhtml

I am trying to extract non-trivial html elements on a page to a C# class. Tags such as:

1. `<input>`
2. `<a>`
3. `<select>`
4. ...

I need to give proper names to the C# class fields representing these HTML elements. But these tags may lack some important attributes, such as:

1. ID
2. Name

Is there any smart way to name these HTML elements, while keep the maximum readability?

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the HTML? In this case give them IDs/classes; you could possibly use `data-` attributes, too, as long as your C# DOM engine allows you to select elements by arbitrary attributes.

Can't you do this? Then you are out of luck and have to access them with selectors/xpath, i.e. by their ancestry and position in the children set of the direct parent element.

Comment: Actually, accessing them is not a problem. I have used HtmlAgilityPack and XPath to locate the elements. I just need to give them proper names.